# How to split equally in value a list in python (Appropriate Value)

Tags: python

```
[28, 7, 11, 8, 9, 7, 27]
```

in

[28, 11, 9],
[27, 8, 7, 7]

The total sum is 97 and i want to split equally and the elements to have close value

Comment: Can you be more precise as to what you mean by "split equally" and "elements to have close value", and what to do when these criteria come into conflict?

Comment: From the above example, what I can infer is that we need to pick a subset of elements whose value is as close to `sum//2` and then the remaining elements will be a part of the other list. This can be done by the `0-1 Knapsack` Dynamic Programming technique in `O(n*W)` where `n` is the number of elements in the list and `W` is the maximum number in the list. Would this time complexity suffice for your application? What are the limits to the size of the given list and the maximum number possible in the list?

Comment: I have a problem at college, sounds like this: At the end of Christmas Eve, Santa emptied his bag in the house of two brothers. The gifts he left had no labels. When the 2 brothers woke up, they wondered how they would share the presents.
Knowing that each gift is a known object and has a certain value (between 1 and 100), write a program that determines the amounts of gifts and how to divide them so that the amounts obtained are as close as possible.
Input:
7 gifts
(bicycle, 28), (coloring book, 7), (game, 11), (plush toy, 8), (ball, 9), (storybook, 7), (skis, 27)

Comment: I turned it into 2 lists, one with the gifts, the second with the prices and I made a dictionary that looks something like this:
{'bicycle': '28', 'coloring book': '7', 'game': '11', 'plush toy': '8', 'ball': '9', 'storybook' : '7', 'skis': '27'}

Comment: I believe you should have your dictionary reversed... meaning the key will be the amounts of gifts and the value of dictionary will be a list containing the names of gifts. Then just apply `0-1 Knapsack DP` as I mentioned earlier. Have a look at `https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/0-1-knapsack-problem-dp-10/`. @Scott Hunter does this sound right?

Comment: That's the price not the amount of gifts, the amount of gifts is 7, do you mean to have a dict with one key, and that will be 7? And then the values will be like : (bicycle, 28), etc... >?!

Comment: @radumarin sorry what I meant was the key of the dictionary will be the prices (0-100)

Answer (score 2):

```
from more_itertools import set_partitions

lst = [28, 7, 11, 8, 9, 7, 27]

print(*min(set_partitions(lst, 2),
           key=lambda p: abs(sum(p[0]) - sum(p[1]))))
```

Output:

```
[28, 11, 9], [7, 8, 7, 27]
```

Comment: Since it is a college assignment I assume it must be implemented manually rather than importing libraries

Comment: @AbhinavSinghal Maybe, maybe not. Question doesn't say that, and future readers interested in the same problem might not have such requirements, either.